# What is the standard way of proving that the expression $\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}f(ny)g(s,y) dy$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm sorry if this question is vague. What is the standard way of proving that the expression $\int_{1}^{\infty}\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}f(ny)g(s,y) dy$ is holomorphic ?

Here, $f(y)$ is a fast-decaying function in the Schwarz space, and $s$ is a complex number. I was given $g(s,y)$ that doesn't outrun $f(ny)$. Infinity in both integral and sum makes it difficult to handle. What tools or theorems can I use? I don't want answers but I would really appreciate any idea!

Comment: Morera's Theorem may help.

Comment: Usually DCT is the first thing to try: Assuming $g(-,y)$ is analytic for all $y$ and you want to dominate $\sum f(ny)[g(s+h,y)-g(s,y)]/h$ so you can push the differentiation inside the integral sign, etc.

Comment: First, you should replace $\sum_{n \geq 1}{f(ny)}$ with some $F(y)$ which should also decay fast. The first thing I would try next is, given some complex number $s$ and an open disk $s+rD$ around $s$, to find a bound $|F(y)g(s',y)| \leq H(y)$ for $s' \in s+rD$ and $H(y)$ integrable. This shows that your integral is well-defined as a function of $s'$. But actually, the estimate above, with Fubini and analyticity of the integrand, shows that your integral $I(s')$ satisfies, for $s' \in s+0.5rD$, $I(s')=\int_{s+r\partial D}{\frac{I(u)}{u-s'}du}$, which entails analyticity.